# iTextSharp IExtRenderListener and boundingbox

Tags: itext

I'd like to get bounding box of pdf objects (text and vectorial) but i get strange results

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To renderInfo.SegmentData.Count - 2 Step 2
        Dim x As Single = renderInfo.SegmentData(i)
        Dim y As Single = renderInfo.SegmentData(i + 1)
        Dim a As parser.Vector = New parser.Vector(x, y, 1).Cross(renderInfo.Ctm)
        x = a(parser.Vector.I1)
        y = a(parser.Vector.I2)
        lastRect = New System.util.RectangleJ(x, y, 0, 0)
        If Not IsNothing(lastRect) Then
            If lastRect.X < minX Then
                minX = lastRect.X
            End If
            If lastRect.X > maxX Then
                maxX = lastRect.X
            End If
            If lastRect.Y < minY Then
                minY = lastRect.Y
            End If
            If lastRect.Y > maxY Then
                maxY = lastRect.Y
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

This is the core of my ModifyPath implementation, it works with some PDFs but it doesn't work with few ones ([like this](http://data.sygest.it/download/so_002.zip)).
I'd like to get the same values as GhostScript BoundingBox data :  67 376 561 746

Any ideas?

Comment: The `SegmentData` are **not** only coordinates of corners of the graph, they can also be width and height information (**re**ctangle instruction) or they can be positions of cubic Bézier curve control points (**c**, **v**, **y** instructions). Thus, you must interpret the data in the context of their instruction.